# Interpolation between 2 points for a specified datetime values

Tags: r, interpolation

I'm new to R.
I've a CSV file with the data as shown below.
It has 4000+ rows of data. I'm not able to figure out how to feed the Timestamp data for Approx function.
Below is my code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(pmml) 
library(XML)
library(gmodels)
library(zoo)
library("data.table") 

df <- fread("C:/Users/myprofile/Desktop/test logs/test1.csv",
                  select = c("Timestamp", "Var1"))

head(df)

df[['Timestamp']] <- as.POSIXct(df[['Timestamp']],
                                  format = "%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S:%OS")

seq1 <- zoo(order.by=(as.POSIXlt(seq(min(df$Timestamp), max(df$Timestamp), by=5))))
```

I'm not sure how to use the Approx() function for the Timestamp data.
Please help how to interpolate for "Var1" at any 2 points, for the kind of data that I have.

I get this error

> seq1 <- zoo(order.by=(as.POSIXlt(seq(min(df$Timestamp), max(df$Timestamp), by=5))))
> Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number

```
 dput(df)
structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(1594146600, 1594146609, 
1594146610, 1594146612, 1594146613, 1594146614, 1594146615, 1594146616, 
1594146618, 1594146619, 1594146620, 1594146640, 1594146660, 1594146681, 
1594146701, 1594146721, 1594146741, 1594146761, 1594146782), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, -19L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000002aac2681ef0>, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

```
structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(1594146600, 1594146609, 
1594146610, 1594146612, 1594146613, 1594146614, 1594146615, 1594146616, 
1594146618, 1594146619, 1594146620, 1594146640, 1594146660, 1594146681, 
1594146701, 1594146721, 1594146741, 1594146761, 1594146782), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Var1 = c(-0.02, -0.02, -0.01, 0.26, 0.48, 
0.63, 0.75, 0.86, 0.97, 1.2, 2.27, 4, 4.3, 3.02, 2.23, 1.79, 
1.62, 1.59, 1.63)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: did dput on my data and above is my edited version of data.

Comment: Sorry, I was pointing to an old file earlier. See the corrected code using what you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** Using the last dput output shown in the question (also shown in the Note at the end) we create sequential date/times, `seq1`, fixing code in question and then use `approx` converting the resulting list to a data frame and then read that data frame into a zoo object.

```
library(zoo)

rng <- range(df$Timestamp)
seq1 <- seq(rng[1], rng[2], 5)

dfi <- with(df, data.frame(approx(Timestamp, Var1, seq1)))
z <- read.zoo(dfi)
```

**2)** Alternately use `na.approx`.  `seq1` is from (1) above.  Here we create a zoo object from `df` and merge it with a zero width object with the time grid.  That will introduce NAs which can be filled with `na.approx`.  Then extract the values at the grid.

```
library(zoo)

zz <- read.zoo(df)
z0 <- zoo(, seq1)
na.approx(merge(zz, z0))[time(z0)]
```

### Note

```
df <-
structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(1594146600, 1594146609, 
1594146610, 1594146612, 1594146613, 1594146614, 1594146615, 1594146616, 
1594146618, 1594146619, 1594146620, 1594146640, 1594146660, 1594146681, 
1594146701, 1594146721, 1594146741, 1594146761, 1594146782), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Var1 = c(-0.02, -0.02, -0.01, 0.26, 0.48, 
0.63, 0.75, 0.86, 0.97, 1.2, 2.27, 4, 4.3, 3.02, 2.23, 1.79, 
1.62, 1.59, 1.63)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I'm able to try this out for any 2 set of values and I could follow the code as well. Simple and direct!

Comment: What I had shared is a sample data. There are 4000 rows of data actually. Just want to know if I can interpolate on the entire range or will there be a limitation on the number of rows. I remember earlier seeing that R had some limitation in processing the number of rows.

Comment: The max length of a vector is in the trillions (billions for older 32 bit versions of R).

Comment: Can this dataframe df be used to create a pmml file? I'm looking for storing the output into a pmml file. Please help how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

What is min(df$Timestamp) and max(df$Timestamp)? It's possible that you have NAs in your data and you have to go `max(df$Timestamp, na.rm=T)`. But for your sequence to work best, you should specify from, to and the time interval (you don't always know what unit 5 will default to).
So:
`seq(from=min(df$Timestamp, na.rm=T), to=max(df$Timestamp, na.rm=T), by='5 days'))`

Comment: I was trying to provide a start and end time so used min and max, assuming it will take data from timestamp min and max values. My bad may be. There are no NAs in my data. May be I dont have to use seq . I just want to interpolate any points from my data table.

Comment: I'm not able to figure out how to provide my Timestamp column data for Interpolation with the Var1 column data. I just need to demonstrate interpolation between any 2 Var1 columns values.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes. All I want to try is interpolation in R for Var1 column any 2 points in my data. I was trying to treat the Timestamp column value to use it for Approx function later. Not able to proceed accordingly. Dont know how to handle datetime values for interpolation.

Comment: `approx(df$Timestamp, df$Var1)` seems to work fine. What is the problem? R natively handles timestamps really well

Comment: Tried Approx(df$Timestamp, df$VAr1). It gives the same result as in table. Can I specify a range for this function. Also the timestamp is not periodic. Dont know how that would affect the result.